# Innovation/diffusion model in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo, agent-based-modeling

I'm new to Netlogo and having difficulty grasping this problem.....

Say you have 5,000 agents and each agent has five domains, those domains are given a number based on the agents expertise.  Agents max for all domains is 15 and if the agent has over 7.5 for any domain they are considered an expert.

There are two environments one is clustered by each domain, agents with the highest number with move into that domain area.  Second environment mixed with an expert from each of the five domains collaborating with different domain experts.

This model is to represent cross functional collaboration for innovation in businesses.

I'm having difficulty wrapping my head around the equation or activity to represent collaboration between the agents.

Also, confused about how to represent their connections.  I've looked at Team Assembly on Netlogo and think its similar to what I want to represent.  I am not sure how to quickly set the random matrix up to define the agents expertise.

any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated:)

Thanks in advance for reading and considering your input.

Comment: Are you asking about what distribution to use or how you do it in the language?

Comment: This question is very unclear. But the basic idea when designing a model is to pretend you are an agent. What information do you need to make a decision about what action to take. In your case, pretend you are an expert - how do you decide to collaborate and who to collaborate with? What effect does collaboration have?

Comment: Ok, what I know is..... I need to establish agents and their expertise level in certain areas, the environment is a corporation and there are accounts, sales reps, marketing...blah, blah, blah....5 different areas.  I need to define n = number of agents to these different areas.   Then I need to make the environments, first one is clustered by expertise and the other one involves a more collaborative environment (cross functional) which groups an expert from each department.  The ultimate goal is to see where the innovation or big projects stem from.

Comment: Does that make sense?  Again, super new to the over arching concept of multiple agent based modeling and coding in Netlogo.

Comment: maybe I'll break the problem down as i work through the problem

Comment: probably a good idea. StackOverflow is really intended for answering specific questions like a bug in the code or you can't get syntax correct for something. If you want general approaches, try the NetLogo users group. Having said that, people here are very helpful if you focus on one bit at a time. Also look at the model library for ideas.

Comment: start with the second paragraph I have some ideas.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your feedback JenB and King-Ink

Comment: I'd suggest first writing a simpler model.  You have too many requirements, and that makes it hard to wrap your head around the problem. Start with fewer requirements.  Then, when you get the model working, add a requirement and modify the model, to satisfy that new requirement. (Also, why did you title the post "Innovation/diffusion ..."?  That makes it sound as if a good starting point would be the "Virus on a Network" model or the "Diffusion on a Directed Network" model.  Or maybe the "Virus" model in Biology, "Ising" in Chemistry and Physics, or "AIDS" or "Rumor Mill" in Social Science.)

Comment: You're right, I had to back up and start small....right now I'm trying to group my turtles by color on a specific patch. Here's what I have so far.

Comment: globals [
Patch1            ;;marketing department
Patch2            ;;accounting department
Patch3            ;;IT department
Patch4            ;;admin department
Patch5            ;;research department
]

Comment: turtles-own [
  red?              ;; if true, the person is a marketing expert
  green?            ;; if true, the person is a accounting expert
  blue?             ;; if true, the person is an IT expert
  yellow?           ;; if true, the person is a administration expert
  violet?            ;; if true, the person is a research expert

]

Comment: ;;;
;;; SETUP PROCEDURES
;;;


to setup
  clear-all
  set-default-shape turtles "person"
  setup-turtles
end

to go
  move-turtles
end

Comment: to setup-turtles
  create-turtles initial-number-turtles  ;; create the people, then initialize their variables
  ask turtles [setxy random-xcor random-ycor]
  ask turtles [set color one-of [red green blue violet yellow]]
end

Comment: to setup-departments   ;;  patch procedure
  ask patches [if pycor > 0 and pxcor > -17 [set pcolor 18]] ;; patch1
  ask patches [if pycor < 17 and pxcor > 0 [set pcolor 58]]  ;; patch2
  ask patches [if pycor < 1 and pxcor < 1 [set pcolor 98]]  ;; patch3
  ask patches [if pycor > 0 and pxcor > 0 [set pcolor 49]]  ;; patch4
  ask patches [if pycor > 2 and pxcor < -2 [set pcolor 118]]  ;; patch5
endto go-department

Comment: ask turtles [ if pcolor = red [move-turtle-to-patch1]
                if pcolor = green [ move-to patch2]
                if pcolor = blue [ move-to patch3]
                if pcolor = yellow [move-to patch4]
                if pcolor = violet [ move-to patch5]
  ]
endto setup-crossfunctional_teams
  ;;; code
end


to go-cross_functional
  move-turtles
end


to move-turtles
  ask turtles [
    right random 360
    forward 1
  ]
 end

Comment: @Mars, I did look at those models you suggested and I think there are usable parts but like you said, I need to start smaller and work my way up.  I got a bit confused going that direction.